# FPDF including a php file?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I want to send a dynamic page for printing to labels using Fpdf, however I'm not entirely sure how to get Fpdf to display the contents of my php file.

The php file renders a page with the users url, avatar, custom user background and name in a `contactcard.php` file.

How would i go about sending this to PDF, using Fpdf?

I have tried creating a function but it will not print images in the PDF.

Comment: If you show that you've tried so far, this will help others to help you. Also I'd say you can improve the description what you try to achieve, probably with some little picture that shows what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar thing with a real estate property listing. I've output text and images to a pdf for saving or printing using fpdf and php.

I used a form with hidden fields. Click the form button then it goes to the fpdf page. The form uses Post so I can retrieve the data on the fpdf page with something like...

```
$username = $_POST(username);
```

The way I've included images is to link to the images directly, well kind of. I have an id retrieved from the database which I include in the file name to display the correct image e.g.

```
$image = "http://www.yourdomain.com/img/avatar_$id.jpg";
```

Then you would display them with fpdf like...

```
$pdf->Cell(10,0,$username,0,0);
$pdf->Image($image,30,36);
```

You could use sessions so you don't have to include a form. That should work also. Might be more suitable in your case.

I hope this is what you're after.